# to prevent the user from saving and navigating in field

Tags: iphone

how to prevent navigation and saving button functionality in this window. although i know its pre added functionality..????

[image: to stop the working of save and to prevent navigation]

Comment: I have to ask, how do you intend for the user to do anything useful with this view if you remove the buttons?

Comment: actually i have inserted the data into this view from webservices and i want this view for displaying data. i dont want user to store data in contacts or allow editing!

Comment: @Ben alpert:thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ABNewPersonViewController` doesn't expose it's UINavigationBar and even if it did, modifying it would probably be grounds for rejection. I'd suggest creating your own contact view.

Comment: when i tried to make this kind of view. But i am not able to allocate the uiimageview in IB before first two row!!

Comment: can u gve me any refrence or link with which i can get help to design this view?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `UITableView` to make your own view; check out the **EditableDetailView** sample code for a nice example.

Comment: is it in apple developers library?